# Encrypt a long text string using RSA encryption only

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am using the RSA encryption code given on [this link](http://hayageek.com/rsa-encryption-decryption-openssl-c/) for encrypting strings such as the following with 128 byte public keys:

```
[7998725336653383203658644639673805448553730986337128386926545744008381384348409264866333582258561179132241508936069720871865895053632019929236743348039021, 1993938860438750843589842757968313427718259534664174282914852335272086243792497573680387148722647412680490224484736059954284097163105446004304579443902885]
```

Since the string is too long the `RSA_public_encrypt` function returns `-1` and a `null` string. I know that RSA should be used for small sized texts, is there a way around the same ?

I used the `ERR_error_string()` to check the error codes and it returned me the following error code string: `error:0406D06E:lib(4):func(109):reason(110)`.

Now since this question has been marked as a possible duplicate then please let me explain that I need to do it using only RSA because an AES-RSA combination will make the whole system design of the chrome extension that I am writing, much more complex than it is already. I want to keep it as simplified as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt/decrypt long input messages with RSA? \[Openssl, C\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344122/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-long-input-messages-with-rsa-openssl-c)

Comment: Yeah I had seen that and that doesn't solves my purpose, if I do the AES-RSA double encryption thing then that would change the whole of the existing model and make the system much more inefficient. Is it possible to do it in chunks ?

Comment: Inefficient? On the contrary AES is much faster than RSA so only one RSA invocation would be necessary. The other possibility would be to encrypt RSA in chunks (much slower) which is also discussed in the linked question. You can also use bigger moduli, but that doesn't scale.

Comment: Personally I'd drop RSA entirely and use something ECIES like, such as NaCl's box.

Answer (score 4):

The answers above already mention RSA-AES.  This is the right way to go.  You use RSA to trade one small message -- the symmetrical key -- and you can talk all you want using that session key.

The limitation on RSA is a mathematical one, just so you know.  I saw someone once complaining about MS not allowing their RSA to encrypt a big enough message for their purposes.  The problem is that once the message gets about 1/2 as long in digits as the key is, it "rolls over" past zero in the mathematical function -- passes the upper limit of the number field -- and will not decrypt to the same number it started out as.  So this limit cannot be overcome, except in a limited sense by using larger RSA keys.  Or by chunking the message and sending all separately as RSA, but multiple encryptions using that same public/private key pair is discouraged.

I really recommend you go with the RSA/AES hybrid.  You will get much better performance this way than any other way I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Building some sort of RSA-chunking scheme is going to be far more complex and potentially insecure, IMHO, than decrypting a symmetric key and performing simple AES decryption using that key.

As far as efficiency, RSA is going to be orders of magnitudes *slower* than AES, so the trade-off you make is that you give up simplicity (i.e. you give up the simplicity of using AES, in favor of some RSA "chunking") in return for poor performance (you get the slower performance of RSA.)

I would take the well-worn path of the hybrid AES-RSA approach, rather than experimenting with some RSA-only scheme.

Comment: Note that AES should be used in an authenticated mode, such as GCM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use strictly RSA, you need to split up the message into chunks equal to the size of the RSA key and apply RSA multiple times.  Note however that doing so means that each encrypted chunk has its own padding and that RSA is much more computationally expensive than AES.

If the message you're encrypting is large enough, not only will it take more time to process, but the RSA encrypted message might be larger than an RSA encrypted AES key plus an AES encrypted message.

Comment: (1) The main argument is performance. If a good key size like 2048 bit is used, then the ciphertext blowup will only be 5% or 20% dependending on the padding (not counting the last possibly largely unused block). (2) RSA as a block cipher is vulnerable to block reordering when implemented trivially which might completely break the system.

Comment: @dbush I am trying the code for chunked RSA but the decryption is not working correctly always, the code is on this link http://codeshare.io/Ez9q5. Please let me know where am I going wrong ?

Comment: If there's a specific question you have, post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the expected and actual output.

Comment: @dbush Please check a working example here: http://codeshare.io/Ez9q5 The decryption behaviour is random, sometimes it decompresses successfully sometimes it fails.

Comment: @dbush since my sensitive content will always be in the range of 310-320 bytes, I have chosen to use RSA with a 3072 bits key, that has solved the problem and no need for doing RSA chunked encryption anymore.

Comment: This doesn't only lead to horrible performance and ciphertext bloat. You'd also need to invent your own mode of operation for this integrating a MAC. So this is a really bad idea. @bawejakunal Your example uses PKCS#1v1.5 padding which is broken instead of the proper OAEP.